# Is there a way to implement Drag & Drop in Outlook

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are working hard on our different MS Office add-ins and now that we have a production ready version for Word, Excel and PowerPoint our next goal is to have one for Outlook

One of our features here, is to be able to Drag & Drop an e-mail from e.g. Outlook Inbox to our add-in pane, so that a mail can be saved easily in our platform/application… As you know MS Office add-ins is hosted in an iFrame and therefore there is a lot of security around it, and from our spikes we can’t provide Drag & Drop functionality…

Could you please give me some input here… Is this kind of Drag & Drop functionality not doable at this point of time, or is there a way to implement it, or do Microsoft Office have any plan to implement it in the future or something totally third…

Best regards,

René Fedderholdt, Product Owner, KMD WorkZone

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look the [older post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/webdav_101/drag-and-drop-with-outlook). In short, Drag and Drop with Outlook is not supported by code. However there are some techniques which can provide an item drag/drop effect, the above article talks about it.

Comment: As you mention, this is an old post - so next quick question will be:Is this 'Workaround' also doable in office.js Task Pane project...?

Comment: This article was written prior to office.js introduction, so i suspect it. But its worth to see if its doable with office.js or not.

Answer (score 0):

Currently drag-and-drop to the add-in task pane is not a part of the product. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your votes to [the request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13266885-enabling-drag-drop-with-add-ins-commands-and-taskp) and add more details.
Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.